# pandas chunksize - concat inside and outside the loops

Tags: python, pandas

I have to read massive csv files (500 million lines), and I tried to read them with pandas using the chunksize method, in order to reduce memory consumption. But I didn't understand the behaviour of the concat method and the option to read all the file and reduce memory. I'm adding some pseudocode in order to explain what I did so far.

Let's say I'm reading and then concatenate a file with n lines with:

```
iter_csv = pd.read_csv(file.csv,chunksize=n/2)
df = pd.concat([chunk for chunk in iter_csv])
```

Then I have to apply a function to the dataframe to create a new column based on some values:

```
df['newcl'] = df.apply(function)
```

Everything goes fine.
But now I wonder what's the difference between the above procedure and the following:

```
iter_csv = pd.read_csv(file.csv,chunksize=n/2)
for chunk in iter_csv:
    chunk['newcl'] = chunk.apply(function)
    df = pd.concat([chunk])
```

In terms of RAM consumption, I thought that the second method should be better because it applies the function only to the chunk and not to the whole dataframe. But the following issues occur:

1. putting the `df = pd.concat([chunk])` inside the loop returns me a dataframe with a size of n/2 (the size of the chunk), and not the full one;
2. putting the `df = pd.concat([chunk])` outside, after the loop returns the same n/2 dataframe length.

So my doubt is whether the first method (concatenate the dataframe just after the `read_csv` function) is the best one, balancing speed and RAM consumption. And I'm also wondering how may I concat the chunks using the for loop.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Don't you need to concat the df with itself? `df = pd.concat([df, chunk])`?

Comment: Yes thanks! So, should be better to concatenate the dataframe inside the loop instead of build the whole dataframe outside and then apply the function? The RAM consumption is proportional to the size of the chunk, no matter the final dimension of the whole concatenate DataFrame?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, in your previous question you were building a NX graph, the df was just being used to quickly read chunks of lines so you didn't need to persist the df, if you want to load a csv into a df, so long as the df can fit in memory you shouldn't need to chunk it. Chunking is needed if really all you need is some summary calculations or you intermediate calcualations that you can perform without needing the entire df

Comment: How do you handle pd.concat if iter_csv is empty?

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of chunking the data loading, if you finally end-up anyway with entire dataset in the RAM? The main idea for chunking - is to process big dataset piece by piece, not loading whole file into the memory..

In your case, you probably going to save result to output.csv file at the end? so:

```
CHUNK_SIZE = 1000000
fheader = 1
fmodes = ('a', 'w')
output_file = 'output.csv'

for chunk in pd.read_csv('file.csv', chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE):
    chunk['newcl'] = chunk.apply(function)  # your processing (assuming no cross-chunk aggregation
    chunk.to_csv(output_file,
                 mode=fmodes[fheader],      # create or append 
                 header=fheader,            # write csv column names
                 index=False)               # do not save dataframe's index 
    fheader = 0                             # reset fheader flag for the rest of chunks
```

this way only 1 chunk of data will be in the memory at once (theoretically).

P.S. in practice, if you are creating some big tmp_df objects during processing, they might accumulate in ram (memory leak). and even explicitly clearing them with `del tmp_df` and foring `gc.collect()` not always help. I found a workaround: that implementing processing in a separate sub-function - does memory cleaning much better (all local function objects auto-cleared straight away on the function exit).